# Figure out where the biggest files come from

Tags: vue.js, debugging, webpack

I use webpacke to build a VUE 2.X project, and as the project grows the build time significantly increases,

```
            static/img/jsoneditor-icons.256e3ab.svg    36.8 kB          [emitted]
              static/js/app.8c4b5d3ddffad1804418.js    7.19 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  app
         static/js/manifest.eeb2c031c0c552bd70ec.js  799 bytes       1  [emitted]         manifest
static/css/app.5c8abbb61cd67356bc5907eff5cc7866.css    54.4 kB       0  [emitted]         app
```

I'm not sure what caused it, my questions are,

1. The the big JS file the root cause of this problem?
2. For FontAwesome and bootstrap packages, should I include them as a static resource in the index.html, or should I install and compile it via npm?